# Multiple select in 1 SQL query

Tags: sql

I got trouble creating query to get the result that i wanted.
I got 2 tables like below

**Table Customer**

| customer | city | salesperson_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | city A | IPGT1 |
| Customer 2 | city B | IPGT2 |
| Customer 3 | city A | IPGT1 |
| Customer 4 | city C | IPGT2 |
| Customer 5 | city D | IPGT3 |

**Table Visit_plan**

| salesperson_id | city | visit_day | visit_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPGT1 | city A | Monday | 2 |
| IPGT1 | city C | Tuesday | 2 |

I have tried the query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.city, a.salesperson_id, b.visit_day, b.visit_frequency
FROM Customer a
  INNER JOIN Visit_plan b ON a.city = b.city
```

but the result that i got is like below

| city | salesperson_id | visit_day | visit_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city A | IPGT1 | Monday | 2 |
| city C | IPGT1 | Tuesday | 2 |

This is my desired result where a full list of customers with visit_day & visit_frequency displayed as empty if the city not exist in Visit_plan table

| city | salesperson_id | visit_day | visit_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city A | IPGT1 | Monday | 2 |
| city B | IPGT2 |  |  |
| city C | IPGT1 | Tuesday | 2 |
| city D | IPGT3 |  |  |

what is the correct way to do this in 1 SQL query?

Comment: Tip: `a` and `b` are poor tables aliases. Choose aliases that make sense. E.g. `vp` for `Visit_plan`.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: @jarlh sorry I did not use that aliases in my actual code. those aliases just for this question only  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include rows from `Customer` where no corresponding row from `Visit_plan` exists.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.city, a.salesperson_id, b.visit_day, b.visit_frequency
FROM Customer a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Visit_plan b ON a.city = b.city
```